# Centering the dropdown menu in Elementor / Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Can you help me center the dropdown menu from the parent menu please, I was using Elementor in wordpress. I tried this css code but it does nothing:

```
.header-menu {
     left: 50%;
     right: auto;
     text-align: center;
     transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9LQd.jpg

[Screenshot of the inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YntdC.jpg)

Comment: post your complete code or live example

Comment: Sorry ismail, it is currently in a staging site that needs login. I have been trying to inspect the element, can't seem to get the right class or ID that Elementor embeded the menu. I tried to put my own class or ID, but it is not doing anything to it. Maybe use !important?

Comment: You can use elementor header footer plugin

Comment: you can add image

Comment: Thanks Vasim, but I don't want to add another bloated plugin, Elementor Pro is a good enough page builder, I just need a guru to point me to the right direction to add the right css to the right element..:)

Comment: Looks like I am not adding the right class with the child selector. Working fine now adding the child selector.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/4991#issuecomment-564926152):

Add a custom CSS class name to your Elementor menu  ex: *full_center_dropdown*

```
.full_center_dropdown nav ul {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
.full_center_dropdown nav ul a {
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. In the Nav Menu add the following CSS:

   .elementor-nav-menu--dropdown > ul
   {
   text-align: center!important;
   }
2. In the Edit Nav Menu first tab (Content) under disposition > Mobile Dropdown > select: Align = "Center"

And that's it!